# How to get a constant's name given its value

Tags: c#

A firmware manufacturer is shipping an API every now and then that contains a class like this:

```
public static class Manufacturer 
{
  public const ushort FooInc = 1;
  public const ushort BarInc = 2;
  public const ushort BigCompany = 3;
  public const ushort SmallCompany = 4;
  public const ushort Innocom = 5;
  public const ushort Exocomm = 6;
  public const ushort Quarqian = 7;
  // snip... you get the idea
}
```

I have no control over this class, and there is likely to be a new one from time to time, so I don't really want to rewrite it.

In my code I have access to an integer from a data file that indicates the "Manufacturer" of the device that the file came from.

I'd like, if possible, to display the name of the manufacturer on my UI, instead of the number, but the only cross reference I can find is this class.

So, given I have the number "6" from the file, how can I turn that into the text "Exocomm"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way would be to use reflection, enumerate over all constants from that class and check which one has given value. It would be much better to use an `enum` instead of class/constants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep it simple using reflection:

```
   var props = typeof(Manufacturer).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
   var wantedProp = props.FirstOrDefault(prop => (ushort)prop.GetValue(null) == 6);
```

Comment: I have implemented this, but haven't had a chance to verify it works 100% yet.

Comment: If you want to verify this fast simply open a new project, copy the Manufacturer class and paste this..

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:

```
public string FindName<T>(Type type, T value)
{
    EqualityComparer<T> c = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    foreach (FieldInfo  f in type.GetFields
             (BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        if (f.FieldType == typeof(T) &&
            c.Equals(value, (T) f.GetValue(null)))
        {
            return f.Name; 
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also check **[C#: Using Reflection to get constant values](http://ruscoweb.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/c-using-reflection-to-get-constant-values/)**

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to write a script that takes that class as a parameter, and creates an `Enum` class. (so basically, changes the class header to enum, chops the crap before the company name, and change the `;` to `,` for all but the last one.

Then you can just use that enum with the value you have.

Comment: OP mentioned about manufacturer API, probably he can do nothing about existing code.

Comment: @YuliamChandra True and false. The same way he can load and use reflection, he can create the enum.

Comment: If that was automatable, it could be an option. I thought about generating an enum from the class using some kind of codegen tool. I'll try out the reflection suggestion first.

Comment: what's stopping you from automating it ? :) . I have nothing against the reflection, as my original message read .. ANOTHER option ... :)

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be to combine the Reflection option that Amir Popovich and Marcin Juraszek suggested to retrieve the constant value-name relationship via code, with Noctis' suggestion to build an Enum automatically out of it.

If this isn't code that changes often (which I understand is the case) than dynamically building a value-name dictionary and accessing it at runtime has more overhead than statically creating an enum and including it in your project.

Add it as a build step and move the processing time to the compiler, rather than the runtime.

Comment: I like this suggestion. Performance, however, is not critical in this instance, as the rest of the processing done on the files is far more intensive than determining the manufacturer name.